# CSS Auto Width Resize

Tags: php, html, css, width

I am trying to implement a system to make my website fit different size screens. I developed the site on a 1920x1080 screen, so it works fine for anyone with that size screen, but it gets clipped off if a smaller screen is used. I have tried a few different methods that I found online, but am not having any luck. What would you guys recommend?
Thanks a bunch!

Here is my site:http://www.clanrippgaming.net/

Comment: The thing you are trying to do is called "making a website responsive" you can learn about `@media` quires to do that...

Answer (score 0):

you can get inspiration at [zurb foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html) or twitter bootstrap, you can use media queries like

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use percentage instead of pixels. Moreover, you should take a look at [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/).